# Microsoft Media Foundation Webcam Interface

Tags: visual-c++, video, windows-7, webcam, ms-media-foundation

I've been working on a c++ interface to capture images from all types of webcams via the Micrsoft Media Foundation. I've already got a bit of code that can connect with several types of webcams and is able to capture images in different resolutions and formats.

I know that under WinXP it is possible to change different parameters of the webcam (like white balance, exposure time e.g.) by using the Direct Show library. Unfortunately the interface in the Direct Show library that made it possible to easily capture single frames from a webcam is removed from Direct Show under Win7. Does anybody know how I can acces these parameters using Microsoft Media Foundation or any other library that I can combine with the Microsoft Media Foundation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DirectShow` is still good in Windows 7 (the easiest to check is using `GraphEdit` and `AMCap` from Windows SDK). Media Foundation however lacks essential support in earlier versions of Windows.

Comment: I came here with the exact same question as OP (control camera in my MF program) and your answer is basically "you should use DirectShow". Unacceptable so a -1 from me

Comment: @YePhIcK: "You should use DirectShow" if you want to stay with documented functionality - yes the answer is still in good standing as of now.

Comment: I'm not going to argue as I'm using the code from the answer I posted below and it is working as expected. No need to fiddle with the Graph or Filters (it is all under the hood). My code looks *just* like a normal MF code with no DirectShow sprinkled around to cause confusion.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to call a DirectShow QueryInterface method from WMF. Example code is given at [Windows Media Foundation: Controlling Camera Properties](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/pavely/2012/05/19/windows-media-foundation-controlling-camera-properties/).
This should let you set available camera parameters like focus and white balance etc.

```
HRESULT CMFVideoCaptureDlg::SetupCamera(IMFMediaSource* pCameraSource) {
    CComQIPtr<IAMCameraControl> spCameraControl(pCameraSource);
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    if(spCameraControl) {
        long min, max, step, def, control;
        hr = spCameraControl->GetRange(CameraControl_Exposure, &min, &max, &step, &def, &control);
        if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
            hr = spCameraControl->Set(CameraControl_Exposure, 1, CameraControl_Flags_Manual);
    }
    CComQIPtr<IAMVideoProcAmp> spVideo(pCameraSource);
    if(spVideo)
        hr = spVideo->Set(VideoProcAmp_WhiteBalance, 0, VideoProcAmp_Flags_Auto);
    return hr;
}
```

> It turns out Media Foundation does not define any specific interfaces
>   for these tasks. Curiously enough, it implements interfaces defined by
>   its predecessor, DirectShow, on its media source (represented by the
>   IMFMediaSource interface), when that media source is a video camera

Comment: Could you copy-paste the most relevant piece into here? The code/link is not accessible ATM (gives HTTP 500) :(

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/pavely/2012/05/19/windows-media-foundation-controlling-camera-properties/) has the following code and it works like a charm!

```
HRESULT CMFVideoCaptureDlg::SetupCamera(IMFMediaSource* pCameraSource) {
    CComQIPtr spCameraControl(pCameraSource);
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    if(spCameraControl) {
        long min, max, step, def, control;
        hr = spCameraControl->GetRange(CameraControl_Exposure, &min, &max, &step, &def, &control);
        if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
            hr = spCameraControl->Set(CameraControl_Exposure, 1, CameraControl_Flags_Manual);
    }
    CComQIPtr spVideo(pCameraSource);
    if(spVideo)
        hr = spVideo->Set(VideoProcAmp_WhiteBalance, 0, VideoProcAmp_Flags_Auto);
    return hr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IAMCameraControl and IANVideoProcAmp still support White balance,pan,zoom in Windows 8. camera control is so far not part of MFT.We have to use Direct Show to do these things.