# How to detect camera frame loss using Windows media API like Media Foundation or DirectShow?

Tags: c++, windows, image-processing, directshow, ms-media-foundation

I am writing an application for Windows that runs a CUDA accelerated HDR algorithm. I've set up an external image signal processor device that presents as a UVC device, and delivers 60 frames per second to the Windows machine over USB 3.0.

Every "even" frame is a more *underexposed* frame, and every "odd" frame is a more *overexposed* frame, which allows my CUDA code perform a modified [Mertens](https://s3.amazonaws.com/academia.edu.documents/50117961/j.1467-8659.2008.01171.x20161105-8969-7bu6ha.pdf?response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3DExposure_Fusion_A_Simple_and_Practical_A.pdf&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWOWYYGZ2Y53UL3A%2F20200123%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200123T193735Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=6af2f70931aa5ab06139d1883db8bba0b8e5391417e370bb2e5806078f3f0cc0) exposure fusion algorithm to generate a high quality, high dynamic range image.

[Very abstract example of Mertens exposure fusion algorithm here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhPT9.png)

My only problem is that I don't know **how to know when I'm missing frames**, since the only camera API I have interfaced with on Windows (Media Foundation) doesn't make it obvious that a frame I grab with `IMFSourceReader::ReadSample` isn't the frame that was received after the last one I grabbed.

***Is there any way that I can guarantee that I am not missing frames, or at least easily and reliably detect when I have, using a Windows available API like Media Foundation or DirectShow?***

It wouldn't be such a big deal to miss a frame and then have to purposefully "skip" the next frame in order to grab the next oversampled or undersampled frame to pair with the last frame we grabbed, but I would need to know how many frames were actually missed since a frame was last grabbed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [`IAMDroppedFrames::GetNumDropped method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/strmif/nf-strmif-iamdroppedframes-getnumdropped) in DirectShow and chances are that it can be retrieved through Media Foundation as well (never tried - they are possibly obtainable with a method similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36690796/868014)).

> The `GetNumDropped` method retrieves the total number of frames that the filter has dropped since it started streaming.

However I would question its reliability. The reason is that with these both APIs, the attribute which is more or less reliable is a time stamp of a frame. Capture devices can flexibly reduce frame rate for a few reasons, including both external like low light conditions and internal like slow blocking processing downstream in the pipeline. This makes it hard to distinguish between odd and even frames, but time stamp remains accurate and you can apply frame rate math to convert to frame indices.

In your scenario I would however rather detect large gaps in frame times to identify possible gap and continuity loss, and from there run algorithm that compares exposure on next a few consecutive frames to get back to sync with under-/overexposition. Sounds like a more reliable way out.

After all this exposure problem is highly likely to be pretty much specific to the hardware you are using.

Comment: Good answer - I should mention that we have design control over the end device and should be able to control whether frame rate slows or not (or at least detect it). Our image signal pipeline leading up and into the Windows device at this point doesn't have the HDR capability that we need for our use case, so it needs to be done on this device. So yes, our solution to this problem will be very hardware specific, I imagine :)

Answer (score 1):

Normally [MFSampleExtension_Discontinuity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/mfsampleextension-discontinuity-attribute) is here for this. When you use IMFSourceReader::ReadSample, check this.